# Double Scrollbar Issue

Tags: html, css, scrollbar

Hello im currently trying to create a website on Enjin but im having issues with the scrollbar if you check on my website there are 2 scrollbars but i dont want 2.

I tried doing `overflow: hidden` and `overflow-x: hidden`, `overflow-y: hidden` but it doesnt work.

My website: https://www.clashersmc.com/

My Code: https://codepen.io/AndriusTAP/pen/wvMpgbp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `body-wrap-3` div must have some overflow. You can avoid this by setting `overflow-y: hidden;` in your CSS class for this div.

Comment: body-wrap-3? where is that?

Comment: If you inspect your site's HTML file with DevTools, you'll see it somewhere at the top.